# Change email address change notice from WordPress

Tags: email

I need to change the default text of the email which is sent when i change a subscribers email. The text:

```
Hi XYZ,

This notice confirms that your email address on CHL Club Hub was changed to example@example.com.

If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at
example@example.com

This email has been sent to admin@example.com

Regards,
All at PageName
https://www.example.com
```

I also would like to change the password change mail. Is there a documentation about this?

Answer (score 1):

To filter the content of the email sent when a user's email is changed you want the `email_change_email` filter. Docs at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/email_change_email/

Password change email is filtered by `password_change_email`, docs at  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/password_change_email/

You'll be able to search to find examples of how to use these. You'll need to add code to your functions.php or to a plugin to use them.

I found these by going to the Wordpress Code Reference here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/ and searching for 'email'  and selecting only Hooks.